# Ошибка в коде, и помощь в реализации функций

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня появилось сразу 3 вопроса.
Первый заключается в том, что при запуске кода выскакивает ошибка:

```
connect(): AF_INET address must be tuple, not str
```

Код брал с открытого доступа, хотелось бы понять в чем именно заключается проблема.

Вторым вопросом хотелось бы узнать как мне сделать звуковое сопровождение если сервер недоступен, а также сделать проверку не одного адреса, а сразу несколько на постоянной основе.

Понимаю что вопрос может быть банальным, просто не особо силен в питоне, как раз хочу понять как все работает на живом примере)

Вот код:

```
import socket
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys
LOG_FNAME = "network.log"
FILE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), LOG_FNAME)
def send_ping_request(host="127.0.0.1", timeout=3):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host))
    except OSError as error:
        return False
    else:
        s.close()
        return True
def write_permission_check():
        try:
            with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                pass
        except OSError as error:
            print("Ошибка создания файла журнала")
            sys.exit()
        finally:
            pass
def calculate_time(start, stop):
        time_difference = stop - start
        seconds = float(str(time_difference.total_seconds()))
        return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).split(".")[0]
def mon_net_connection(ping_freq=2):
        monitor_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        motd = "Мониторинг сетевого подключения начат в: " + str(monitor_start_time).split(".")[0] + " Отправка запроса ping в " + str(ping_freq) + " секунды"
        print(motd)
        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(motd + "\n")
while True:
        if send_ping_request():
            time.sleep("ping_freq")
        else:
            down_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            fail_msg = "Сетевое соединение недоступно в: " + str(down_time).split(".")[0]
            print(fail_msg)
        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write(fail_msg + "\n")
            i = 0
        while not send_ping_request():
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
        if i >= 3600:
            i = 0
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            continous_message = "Постоянная недоступность сети: " + str(now).split(".")[0]
            print(continous_message)
        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write(continous_message + "\n")
            up_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            uptime_message = "Сетевое подключение восстановлено: " + str(up_time).split(".")[0]
            down_time = calculate_time(down_time, up_time)
            _m = "Подключение к сети было недоступно для " + down_time
            print(uptime_message)
            print(_m)
        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write(uptime_message + "\n")
            file.write(_m + "\n")
        mon_net_connection()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте каждый вопрос отдельно. Если всё валить в один вопрос, то это в будущем затруднит поиск другим пользователям.

Comment: Хорошо, прошу прощения.

Comment: Что касается первого вопроса - кажется, там нужно передавать не только хост, а пару из хоста и порта, примерно так: s.connect((host, port))

Comment: Попробовал с портом, все получилось, спасибо большое, но работает он почему-то только на адресах, которые не дают ответа, в противном случает он просто молчит :(

Comment: Тогда лучше оформить это отдельным вопросом с подробностями - пример кода, как вы его вызываете, и что именно вы понимаете под "молчит". В этот вопрос уже вряд ли кто-то придёт. А новый вопрос, если его сразу нормально оформить, скорее всего кто-нибудь знающий увидит.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую более детально все описать. Спасибо за наставление.